# Oracle APEX_WEB_SERVICE MAKE_REST REQUEST raise ORA-29273 and ORA-24247

Tags: oracle, rest, web-services

I'm working on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production and I need to develop a stored procedure that access an API, I have to retrieve the endpoint

```
https://api.my.host:8443/rest/ec/617643
```

I have set the oracle Wallet and added the certificate like this:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /home/oracle/walletapi -pwd walletapi2022 -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet /home/oracle/walletapi -trusted_cert -cert /tmp/api.my.host.cer -pwd walletapi2022
```

I have set the ACE

```
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
    host => 'api.my.host'
    ,lower_port => 8443
    ,upper_port => 8443
    ,ace => XS$ACE_TYPE(
                        privilege_list => XS$NAME_LIST('http')
                        ,principal_name => 'MYUSER'
                        ,principal_type => XS_ACL.ptype_db
                    )
);
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_WALLET_ACE (
    wallet_path    => 'file:/home/oracle/walletapi'
    ,ace            => XS$ACE_TYPE(
                        privilege_list => XS$NAME_LIST('use_client_certificates', 'use_passwords')
                        ,principal_name => 'MYUSER'
                        ,principal_type => XS_ACL.ptype_db
                    ));
```

[Documentarion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_networkacl_adm.htm#ARPLS74575)

In my stored procedure, I try this:

```
... 
l_clob := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(
               p_url         => 'https://api.my.host:8443/rest/ec/617643'
               ,p_http_method => 'GET'
               ,p_wallet_path => 'file:/home/oracle/walletapi'
               ,p_wallet_pwd  => 'walletapi2022'
);
...
```

[Documentation](https://%20https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1955)

and this error is raised

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1182
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 782
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1127
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 756
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1023
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1371
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 626
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Comment: you need to create an access control list 'rule' that says it's ok for the db to reach out on the network a la https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1

Comment: found the ACL way here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services but CREATE_ACL and ASSIGN_ACL are deprecated so I understand that they are totally replaced by ACE

Answer (score 0):

Applying the solution with `CREATE_ACL` and `ASSIGN_ACL` changes only the value of the ACL column in `DBA_NETWORK_ACLS` and `DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES` views. So I removed ACLs and PRIVs and restart.

Reviewing this question, I noticed that this error is for "APEX_210222" which is one of the schemas created during Apex installation.
I tried

```
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
    host => 'api.my.host'
    ,lower_port => 8443
    ,upper_port => 8443
    ,ace => XS$ACE_TYPE(
                    privilege_list => XS$NAME_LIST('http')
                    ,principal_name => 'APEX_210222'
                    ,principal_type => XS_ACL.ptype_db
                )
```

and the `web_service_request` is now working correctly.